# How to set the custom UserModel field value upon creation of the user in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin, django-custom-user

I have a custom `UserModel` which has a `CharField` named as `pbc_id`. I want it to be set as something like below:

```
pbc_id = "PBC-" + str(user.pk)
```

In other words, I want to attach the newly created user's primary key value at the end of the string "PBC-" and then assign this value to the `pbc_id` field.

I have kind of done it, but it only work when I create a `superuser` using the terminal. But when I create a normal user using Django Administration Interface, it does not work and `pbc-id` gets empty value.

My `User` model is below:

```py
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):    
    username = models.CharField(max_length=254, null=True, blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254, unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=254, null=True, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=254, null=True, blank=True)
    pbc_id = models.CharField(max_length=254, null=True, blank=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_candidate = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_voter = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    EMAIL_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    objects = UserManager()

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return "/users/%i/" % (self.pk)
```

My `UserManager` class is below:

```py
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def _create_user(self, email, password, is_staff, is_superuser, is_candidate, is_voter, **extra_fields):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Users must have an email address')

        now = timezone.now()
        email = self.normalize_email(email)

        user = self.model(
            username=email,
            email=email,
            is_staff=is_staff, 
            is_active=True,
            is_superuser=is_superuser, 
            is_candidate=is_candidate,
            is_voter=is_voter,
            last_login=now,
            date_joined=now, 
            **extra_fields
        )
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        user.pbc_id = "PBC-" + str(user.pk)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_user(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        user = self._create_user(email, password, False, False, False, False, **extra_fields)
        user.pbc_id = "PBC-" + str(user.pk)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        
        return user


    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        user=self._create_user(email, password, True, True, False, False, **extra_fields)
        return user
```

In `admins.py`, I have `UserAdmin` class a below:

```py
class UserAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('username', 'email', 'password', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'last_login')}),
        ('Permissions', {'fields': (
            'is_active', 
            'is_staff', 
            'is_superuser',
            'is_candidate',
            'is_voter',
            'groups', 
            'user_permissions',
        )}),
    )
    add_fieldsets = (
        (
            None,
            {
                'classes': ('wide',),
                'fields': ('email', 'password1', 'password2')
            }
        ),
    )

    list_display = ('username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'pbc_id', 'is_staff', 'is_candidate', 'is_voter', 'last_login')
    list_filter = ('is_staff', 'is_candidate', 'is_voter', 'is_superuser', 'is_active', 'groups')
    search_fields = ('email',)
    ordering = ('email',)
    filter_horizontal = ('groups', 'user_permissions',)
```

Comment: Why do you even need to store that in the database? If all you want to do is display that why don't you do so?

Comment: Because I need to access it in various templates in the frontend and then access user using `pbc_id` field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After hours of searching, I think I got it. You have to override the save method saving the object (see def save_model() at bottom), then assign the "pbc_id" + obj.id to the field, then obj.save()

also changed this
class UserAdmin(BaseUserAdmin)
To this:
class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

```
fieldsets = (
    (None, {'fields': ('username', 'email', 'password', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'last_login','pbc_id')}),
    ('Permissions', {'fields': (
        'is_active',
        'is_staff',
        'is_superuser',
        'is_candidate',
        'is_voter',
        'groups',
        'user_permissions',
    )}),
)
add_fieldsets = (
    (
        None,
        {
            'classes': ('wide',),
            'fields': ('email', 'password1', 'password2',)
        }
    ),
)

list_display = ('username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'pbc_id', 'is_staff', 'is_candidate', 'is_voter', 'last_login')
list_filter = ('is_staff', 'is_candidate', 'is_voter', 'is_superuser', 'is_active', 'groups')
search_fields = ('email',)
ordering = ('email',)
filter_horizontal = ('groups', 'user_permissions',)

def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
    super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)
    obj.pbc_id = "PBC-" + str(obj.pk)
    obj.save()

admin.site.register(models.User, UserAdmin)
```

Comment: this did not work

Comment: I thought it would work, but unfortunately it did not. Do I need to do the `makemigrations` and `migrate` step again after saving the code to make it work or is there any other reason for its not working?

Comment: Also as per you suggested to save the instance first and then do the value assignment to `pbc_id`, as I did in `create_superuser()` method. Actually, I did not do that in `create_superuser()` method, I did it in the main `_create_user()` method, so as it works for `create_superuser()`, it should have worked for `create_user()` method as well, which it does not. Please have a look again.

Comment: I edited my answer.  I got it working on my system.  Sorry, the code's a little weird when I pasted it. I couldn't get it to line up correctly.